# ActiveCollab how long does an API token last?

Tags: activecollab

H ow long does an API token last? I recently had an API token change and was wondering how long do these normally last? I updated my API to the new token but wanted to know how often it changes.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveCollab API don't expire by default. Users can delete them, so make sure that you have a mechanism of detecting when token no longer works.